# Why is followers_count returning as undefined using Twit - Twitter API on Node.js?

Tags: node.js, api, twitter

I'm trying to display the amount of followers a user has in a specific location using Twit on Node.js. In this example I'm trying to show users from Bristol, but I only want to display the amount of followers they have. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here exactly, but it's displaying undefined

`

```
var Twit = require('twit');

var T = new Twit({
  consumer_key:         'my # is here',
  consumer_secret:      'my # is here',
  access_token:         'my # is here',
  access_token_secret:  'my # is here',
  timeout_ms:           60*1000,  // optional HTTP request timeout to apply to all requests.
})

var bristol = '51.454782,-2.596314,5mi';

var params = {
  geocode: bristol,
  count: 8
}

T.get('search/tweets', params, gotData);

function gotData(err, data, response) {
  var tweets = data.statuses;
  for (var i = 0; i < tweets.length; i ++){
    console.log(tweets[i].followers_count);
  }
}
```

`